# Keyboard shortcut to open links on the windows taskbar

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

Is there a way to select the "Links" part of the taskbar with a keyboard shortcut.  I have a script there I want to run a lot and am getting tired of clicking the small buttons.

(It is similar to the WIN+# to open a program on the taskbar (Or WIN+T to select the first one and let you go up or down with the arrow keys), but the sections are separate.)

[image: Example picture of the "links" that I want to click]

(I did find this, but I was hoping not to have to resort to AutoHotKey stuff. http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/182028-keyboard-shortcut-taskbars-address-toolbar.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must left click on the desktop and then: TAB + TAB + TAB + left or right arrow key. The right mouse click is also a key on my keyboard under shift.

Comment: Up and down arrow keys also Works. :)

Comment: Not 100% what I was looking for, but good enough!  :)  Thanks